# A question about elliptic curves and finite fields in bilinear pairings

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

Based on what mentioned in the paper "Pairings For Cryptographers"
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X08000449
the two inputs of a pairing map are two members of two additive groups on elliptic curves, while the output is an element of a multiplicative group on a finite field. 
[image]
I would like to know is there any mathematical or technical advantages for a multiplicative finite filed group (in compare with an additive elliptic curve group)? or is there any mathematical or technical disadvantages for an additive elliptic curve group (in compare with multiplicative finite filed group)?
The following image shows this question more accurate.
[image]
Please help me
[image]

Comment: The setting described in the paper is the only we currently know that provides pairings with all required properties. You do not really have a choice (besides which curves and concrete pairing map to use).

Comment: I replayed you at the end of my question beacause I cannot insert formula here

Comment: Formulas can be inserted here with common Latex notation, by using '$     $'.

Comment: See [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) for formatting help.

Comment: The mathematical disadvantage for $E(F_p)$ as the target group $G_T$ is that no such construction exists.

Comment: dear mikeazo, I know I know and   I didn’t mentioned that is the target for pairing. I said in PAIRING-FREE the scheme is rely on $E(F_p)$. Some scheme like this 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025510001519 
I want to compare a pairing-based scheme with a pairing-FREE one. So I need to know what is the disadvantages of pairing-FREE schemes.

Comment: What pairing-free scheme are you looking at?

Comment: For example check this link 
sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025510001519

the authors compared the pairing free scheme with pairing based one (reference 14 of the mentioned link) authors claimed that pairing free ones are more efficient. However there exist many pairing based schemes, what's the advantage of them? I traced my question. Maybe I can get the answer if I know that what is the advantage of multiplicative group based on a finite field. Or what is the disadvantage of an ECC based group? Please review my question again and focus on $G_1$ and $G_T$.

Comment: sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025510001519